# google maps v3 markers and infoboxes not showing

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a map with the Google Maps API but despite copying existing Javascript from "v3_simpleMap_InfoBoxA.html" (which renders fine in a browser) and tweaking I am not able to get the markers to display on the map. The map renders and the Javascript has been validated with JSLint - no errors.

I was able to get a single point to display with an Infobox, but not multiple. I am not that good at Javascript, my apologies, but have scoured Stackoverflow and cannot find the solution. Here is a code snippet:

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.13/src/infobox.js"></script>

<script>
var ib = new InfoBox();

function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.708833, -70.152917),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  mapTypeControl        : true,
   mapTypeControlOptions:     {
       style  : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
},
   panControl            : false,
   rotateControl         : false,
   scaleControl          : false,
   streetViewControl     : false,
   zoomControl           : true,
   zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
  }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() { ib.close() ;});
var sites = [
  ['Chase Garden Creek', -70.22610, 41.73147, 11, '<p>Chase Garden Creek <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/chase-garden-creek">About Chase Garden Creek</a></p>'],
  ['Howes Pasture', -70.19919, 41.73693, 10, '<p>Howes Pasture <br/>Dennis <br/><a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/howes-pasture/">About Howes Pasture</a></p>'],
  ['Bass River Park', -70.17955, 41.66551, 9, '<p>Bass River Park <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/bass-river-park">About Bass River Park</a></p>'],
  ['Coles Pond at Crowes Pasture', -70.13601, 41.75482, 8, '<p>Coles Pond <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/coles-pond">About Coles Pond</a></p>'],
  ['Paddocks Path', -70.17391, 41.74343, 7, '<p>Paddocks Path <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/paddocks-path">About Paddocks Path</a></p>'],
  ['Dorothy Connors Bell Conservation Area', -70.16389, 41.71962, 6, '<p>Dorothy Connors Bell Conservation Area <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/">About DCB Conservation Area</a></p>'],
  ['Sesuit Neck Road', -70.17122, 41.74698, 5, '<p>Sesuit Neck Road <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/sesuit-neck-road">About Sesuit Neck Road</a></p>'],
  ['Old Fort Field', -70.19989, 41.73325, 4, '<p>Old Fort Field <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/old-fort-field">About Old Fort Field</a></p>'],
  ['Black Foot Path', -70.17214, 41.74350, 3, '<p>Black Foot Path <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/black-foot-path">About Black Foot Path</a></p>'],
  ['Swan River Road', -70.15602, 41.65743, 2, '<p>Swan River Road <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/swan-river-road">About Swan River Road</a></p>'],
  ['Coles Pond Bog', -70.14153, 41.75368, 1, '<p>Coles Pond Bog <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/coles-pond-bog">About Coles Pond Bog</a></p>']
];
setMarkers(map, sites);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "loading..."

});
}

function createMarker(site, map){
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(site[1], site[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        // Add visible and draggable below
        draggable: true,
        visible: true,
        title: site[0],
        zIndex: null,
        // Above, changed from site [3] - no effect
        html: site[4] /*,  Site down at test time, skip icon
        icon: "http://www.testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/favicon.jpg" */
    });
 // Begin example code to get custom infobox
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 6px; background: white; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; padding: 5px; border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = marker.html;

    var myOptions = {
             content: boxText,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.12/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
              opacity: 0.75,
              width: "280px"
             },
            closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            setVisible: true,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    // end example code for custom infobox
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
     ib.close();
     ib.setOptions(myOptions);
     ib.open(map, this);
    });
    return marker;
}

function setMarkers(map, markers) {

 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   createMarker(markers[i], map);
 }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
     </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>www.testsite.com test file March 29, 2015</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
       }
     </style>
          </head>
   <body>
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @Craicerjack - Would you be so kind as to be more specific, i.e. show me exactly which piece of code I should move to where? As I said, I am not good at Javascript (though at least I got a map to show:)

Comment: nevermind - it wasnt the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your latitude and longitude reversed (your markers are all in Antarctica).

[fiddle showing markers](http://jsfiddle.net/f5xfbw3r/)

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5xfbw3r/1/)

code snippet (reversed site[1] and site[2] in the createMarker function):

```js
var ib = new InfoBox();

function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.708833, -70.152917),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  mapTypeControl        : true,
   mapTypeControlOptions:     {
       style  : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
},
   panControl            : false,
   rotateControl         : false,
   scaleControl          : false,
   streetViewControl     : false,
   zoomControl           : true,
   zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
  }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() { ib.close() ;});
var sites = [
  ['Chase Garden Creek', -70.22610, 41.73147, 11, '<p>Chase Garden Creek <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/chase-garden-creek">About Chase Garden Creek</a></p>'],
  ['Howes Pasture', -70.19919, 41.73693, 10, '<p>Howes Pasture <br/>Dennis <br/><a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/howes-pasture/">About Howes Pasture</a></p>'],
  ['Bass River Park', -70.17955, 41.66551, 9, '<p>Bass River Park <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/bass-river-park">About Bass River Park</a></p>'],
  ['Coles Pond at Crowes Pasture', -70.13601, 41.75482, 8, '<p>Coles Pond <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/coles-pond">About Coles Pond</a></p>'],
  ['Paddocks Path', -70.17391, 41.74343, 7, '<p>Paddocks Path <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/paddocks-path">About Paddocks Path</a></p>'],
  ['Dorothy Connors Bell Conservation Area', -70.16389, 41.71962, 6, '<p>Dorothy Connors Bell Conservation Area <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/">About DCB Conservation Area</a></p>'],
  ['Sesuit Neck Road', -70.17122, 41.74698, 5, '<p>Sesuit Neck Road <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/sesuit-neck-road">About Sesuit Neck Road</a></p>'],
  ['Old Fort Field', -70.19989, 41.73325, 4, '<p>Old Fort Field <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/old-fort-field">About Old Fort Field</a></p>'],
  ['Black Foot Path', -70.17214, 41.74350, 3, '<p>Black Foot Path <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/black-foot-path">About Black Foot Path</a></p>'],
  ['Swan River Road', -70.15602, 41.65743, 2, '<p>Swan River Road <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/swan-river-road">About Swan River Road</a></p>'],
  ['Coles Pond Bog', -70.14153, 41.75368, 1, '<p>Coles Pond Bog <br/>Dennis <br/> <a href="http://www.testsite.com/properties/coles-pond-bog">About Coles Pond Bog</a></p>']
];
setMarkers(map, sites);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "loading..."

});
}

function createMarker(site, map){
    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(site[2], site[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: siteLatLng,
        map: map,
        // Add visible and draggable below
        draggable: true,
        visible: true,
        title: site[0],
        zIndex: null,
        // Above, changed from site [3] - no effect
        html: site[4] /*,  Site down at test time, skip icon
        icon: "http://www.testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/favicon.jpg" */
    });
 // Begin example code to get custom infobox
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 6px; background: white; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; padding: 5px; border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = marker.html;

    var myOptions = {
             content: boxText,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.12/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
              opacity: 0.75,
              width: "280px"
             },
            closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            setVisible: true,
            pane: "floatPane",
            // enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    // end example code for custom infobox
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
     ib.close();
     ib.setOptions(myOptions);
     ib.open(map, this);
    });
    return marker;
}

function setMarkers(map, markers) {
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var marker = createMarker(markers[i], map);
   bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
 }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.13/src/infobox.js"></script>
   <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I had been struggling with this for a while - I've seen other (brilliant) answers of yours on here.... This map with markers, which wasn't working (obviously), was the last item to complete on a website for a client. Thank you so much!